# Closures to get variable in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, authentication, express

I am working on thesis software for get variable in closures.

This is my code in node.js

```
var kepala = express.basicAuth(authentikasi);
// authenticate for login 

function authentikasi(user, pass, callback) {
    // declrare my database mongodb
    db.collection('ak_teacher', function (err, data) {
        data.findOne({
            'tch_name': {
                '$regex': user
            }
        }, function (err, level) {

            console.log(level); // monitor data

            if (level == null) {
                console.log('Nilai database kepala sekolah masuk Null ulangi login');
                callback(null);
            } else {

                var a = level.tch_name;
                var b = level.tch_password;

                var c = level.sch_id; // (i need this variable for next code) 

                var result = (user === a && pass === b);
                console.log("id Sekolah : " + c);
                callback(null /* error */ , result);
            }
        });
    });
};

var tes = authentikasi(); // (in here i dont know declare for get my variable c)

app.get('/siswa_2', kepala, function (req, res) {
    // i use variable in here                            
    var sch_id = tes;
    console.log("id school in query :" + sch_id);
    console.log('Menampilkan Seluruh data Siswa');
    db.collection('ak_student', function (err, collection) {
        collection.find({
            "sch_id": sch_id
        }).toArray(function (err, items) {
            console.log(items);
            res.send(items);

        });
    });
});
```

I am trying to get variable `c`.

Comment: That is one awfully formatted code...

Comment: what closure do you need? what variable in what function?

Comment: Yet another person wanting to return a value from async code. I've already answered three similar questions this week and I only did that because I was tired of closing questions like this as duplicate because it's harder finding an answer I liked than simply answering the question. We need a good, well known community answer for this.

Comment: my code in node.js i am use framework express

Comment: please help me for get variable c for use in var tes..
i dont know use logic for get it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#basicAuth), you're supposed to call back with a user object. You can simply put your `c` variable on there:

```
var kepala = express.basicAuth(authentikasi);

function authentikasi(user, pass, callback) {
    // declrare my database mongodb
    db.collection('ak_teacher', function (err, data) {
        data.findOne({
            'tch_name': {
                '$regex': user
            }
        }, function (err, level) {
            console.log(level); // monitor data

            if (level == null) {
                console.log('Nilai database kepala sekolah masuk Null ulangi login');
                callback(null);
            } else {
                var a = level.tch_name;
                var b = level.tch_password;
                var c = level.sch_id; // (i need this variable for next code) 

                if (user === a && pass === b) {
                    console.log("id Sekolah : " + c);
                    callback(null, {name: a, id: c});
//                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                } else
                    callback(null, false);
            }
        });
    });
};
// don't try to authenticate outside of the request context

app.get('/siswa_2', kepala, function (req, res) {
    var sch_id = req.user.id;
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^
    console.log("id school in query :" + sch_id);
…
});
```

Comment: are u genius ^_^ thanks brother i am 2 day working this code i am confused are u genius.. God Bless u friends

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `c` into the callback as well to get it's value:

```
callback(null /* error */, result, c);
```

Then call `authentikasi` like this:

```
// Note, since this callback is called by passing "c"
// as the third argument, this is how we assign it to "tes"
//                                             |
//                                             |
//                                             V
authentikasi(user,pass,function(unused,result,tes) {
  app.get('/siswa_2', kepala, function(req, res) {
    var sch_id = tes;
    console.log("id school in query :" +sch_id);
    console.log('Menampilkan Seluruh data Siswa');
    db.collection('ak_student', function(err, collection) {
      collection.find({"sch_id":sch_id}).toArray(function(err, items) {
        console.log(items);
        res.send(items);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: please wait i am try it now

Comment: hmmm i am try it but error.. user, pass not defined 
authentikasi i am use for login i am having login but i am need variable c for declare next my code in get /siswa

Comment: The function looks like this: `function authentikasi (user, pass, callback) {}` which means that it expects you to pass a username string, a password string and a callback function. Calling it as `authentikasi()` does not make sense at all. This is really basic programming knowledge of how functions work in any language. If you don't even understand this I don't see how anyone can expect you to write javascript which requires knowledge of anonymous functions, closures, asynchronous/event oriented programming etc.

Comment: Sorry to all other stackoverflow members but I'm writing this in Malay to make sure there's not misunderstanding: Sorry tapi "I am having login" tu tak betul. Code ni tak akan login sebab anda tak beri username dan password kepada function `authentikasi` untuk dibandingkan dengan level.tch_name dan level.tch_password.

Comment: i am use this tutorial : [http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-basic-authentication] Single-Route Authentication in my code have database mongodb i am use username and password..
in my database i am have var c = sch_id (school id) i am get it for my next declare var c.. ia am have trouble for closure to get variable c this please help me.

Comment: my english bad sorry....
username and password in my database ak_teacher i am have login for my app.. i am from indonesia sorry..

Comment: saya tulis bahasa indonesia : bisa login untuk username dan password ada di database ak_teachernya begitu authentikasi meminta username dan password maka akan melakukan pencocokan saat pencarian dan bila didapatkan maka dapat login.. yang jadi permasalahan adalah dalam database ak_teacher itu terdapat id sekolah yang mau saya gunakan untuk mendeklarasikan variabel tes = id sekolah dari dalam proses authentikasi cuma susah sekali untuk mendapatkan id sekolah itu ditarik keluar clousurenya.

Comment: i am use this tutorial = [http://howtonode.org/what-is-this] but error undefined..

Answer (score 0):

You could also take advantage of [locals](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals):

> Response local variables are scoped to the request, thus only
>   available to the view(s) rendered during that request / response
>   cycle, if any. Otherwise this API is identical to app.locals.
>
> This object is useful for exposes request-level information such as
>   the request pathname, authenticated user, user settings etcetera.

Assigning `c` to `res.locals.c` should let you use it in later elements of that particular request and subsequent response.

Comment: thanks for u answer. i am need variable id school in my database ak_teacher for declare my code search by id school.. i am have trouble clousure to get variable C = sch_id in ak_teacher..

Comment: `res.locals.id = level.sch_id;` which will then let you use the id as `res.locals.id` later on in request/response handling.